# I'm quite confused about the convergence of pix2pix cGAN, how can we tell whether my model is well trained?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Usually we will see decreasing loss for regular CNN model, but for GAN, it seems to be not that simple. How can we tell whether my model is well trained?

Answer (score 1):

Create a test set, by taking a subset of the training set (make sure to **not** train on this test set!). Then evaluate the model against the given labels in the test set.

Also, this trick is very useful generally, since it works for any supervised machine learning model.